# Limit words that also take numbers in consideration

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im using thess functions to limit titles to 3 words:

```
function trim_words(text, limit){
var words = text.split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/,limit);
theNewString=words.join(" ");
return theNewString;
}
jQuery('#title').keyup(function(){
    jQuery(this).val(trim_words(jQuery(this).val(),3));
});
```

My problem is that i cant use number as separate words.
For example

> "Hello my2 test"

its ok
But if i try

> "Hello 2 test"

number 2 gets deleted.

I know the problem must be in the regex but i know nothing about it. I tried

```
text.split(/\b[\s,\.-:;\d]*/,limit);
```

but no luck at all. 
Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I hope, I'm not wrong, but afaik the \s is for digits and whitespaces, so if you remove it, it could work.

Comment: Nope, it's for whitespaces only.

Comment: My answer was before the one you've chosen as valid... Anyway, glad you have it working.

Comment: Sorry both says= answered 43 mins ago and the @WilQu one was explained a bit more . But i voted up you answer as well.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `-` character. `[\.-:]` means "everything between `.` and `:`". which includes digits.

```
text.split(/\b[\s,\.\-:;]*/,limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape - inside [].

```
/\b[\s,\.\-:;]*/
```

Hope this helps.